# Convert Outlook mail into Byte[]

Tags: arrays, email, outlook, byte, vsto

We have created an application using Visual Studio for Office (using C# as code language) which will be deployed in Outlook. The functionality of the application is,

1) The user will select multiple mails from the Outlook.

2) User has to invoke the "Submit" button which is deployed in outlook using VSTO.

3) Upon clicks of "Submit" button, SharePoint site will be connected and the mails which are selected in first step will be moved to SharePoint List.

The above said functionality successfully implemented. but when the files are being copied in SharePoint, the end user facing some slowness which is leading to bring irresponsive (Loader icon is displayed) mode of Outlook.

Based on the analysis, we came to know that the slowness occurring when the outlook mails are copied in local folder during the process. We are copying the outlook mail in local folder to convert into byte[], because there is no direct option available to convert outlook mail into byte[] without saving. To reduce the slowness, we have put the entire process in Background worker process, even then slowness is occurring which is leading to make outlook as irresponsive.

Can you help us is there any alternate way available to convert into byte[] without saving into local? If there is no alternative option, how can we avoid the slowness when the file is being copied?

Answer (score 0):

Local file access performance hit is negligible compared to the time it actually takes to retreive the data, especially if your are using an online connection. Make sure the cached mode is turned on for the store hosting the messages you are saving.